# storing value in session variable, and checking it

Tags: php, javascript

i have made a login form on a light box using a javascript function. Now i want to store a value on session variable, so to check if the user has logined , and not to show him login lightbox again and again on his navigations on the page.. My javascript function is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    function createlightbox()  
    {  
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';  
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'  
    }  
    function closelightbox()  
    {  
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';  
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'  
    } 
     function checksession()  
    {  if (admin=="admin")
    {closelightbox();}
    else
    {createlightbox();}  
    } 

function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
 if(form.name.value == "admin" && form.password.value == "admin")
  {
    closelightbox();
     var admin = <?php $_SESSION['Admin']= 1; ?>

  }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("error").style.display='block';/*displays error message*/
  }
}      
</script>
```

And i m calling the checksession function in my forms onsubmit event as

```
<form id="Admin" onreset="checksession()">
```

The problem is, on every reset or submit of form, even on the page changes, the login form is shown. Why it is not checking the check session function. 
Please tell me any fault i m making

Comment: Are you aware that JavaScript and PHP are different languages? Your code is the IT equivalent of Spanglish, but Spanglish does not need to be run by a computer.

Comment: yes i m aware of, but after making the changes, the results are the same, now please would you find some other faults.

Comment: There's nothing to fix here. You're just typing random code with the hope that it'll eventually run.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure where your conditions are.
but the following code should present in php script that generates your lightbox:

```
<?php echo '<script> var admin ='.$_SESSION['Admin'].'</script>'; ?>
```

(to check above is working correctly, you could View source code of your page and see if there is a line like: `<script> var admin =1</script>`)

the following should be before you access admin variable setted above:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
.... //other code

 function checksession()  
    {  if(admin =="admin")
    {closelightbox();}
    else
    {createlightbox();}  
    } 
....
```

also note that `if` statement should compare `==` not assign `=`

Comment: The light box is generated as the page loads. It is closed by a javascript function, On closing it, after sign in, i have written your line of code as  var admin = <?php $_SESSION['Admin']; ?>  But it looks like, now the check(form) function is not working at all.

Comment: and again you assigning `var admin = <?php $_SESSION['Admin']= 1; ?>`, yet you checking `admin=="admin"` - it needs to be either 'admin' or 1